# How to make several threads read several files without interference?

Tags: c, thread-safety, pthreads, mutex

I am studying mutexes and I am stuck in an exercise. For each file in a given directory, I have to create a thread to read it and display its contents (no problem if order is not correct).

So far, the threads are running this function:

```
void * reader_thread (void * arg)
{   

    char * file_path = (char*)arg;
    FILE * f;
    char temp[20];
    int value;

    f=fopen(file_path, "r");
    printf("Opened %s.\n",file_path);

    while (fscanf(f, "%s",temp)!=EOF)
        if (!get_number (temp, &value)) /*Gets int value from given string (if numeric)*/
             printf("Thread %lu -> %s: %d\n", pthread_self(), file_path, value );

    fclose(f);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

Being called by a function that receives a `DIR` pointer, previously created by `opendir()`.
(I have omitted some error checking here to make it cleaner, but I get no error at all.)

```
int readfiles (DIR * dir, char * path)
{

    struct dirent * temp = NULL;        
    char  * file_path;
    pthread_t thList [MAX_THREADS];
    int nThreads=0, i;

    memset(thList, 0, sizeof(pthread_t)*MAX_THREADS);
    file_path=malloc((257+strlen(path))*sizeof(char));      

    while((temp = readdir (dir))!=NULL && nThreads<MAX_THREADS) /*Reads files from dir*/
    {

        if (temp->d_name[0] != '.')                     /*Ignores the ones beggining with '.'*/
        {   
            get_file_path(path, temp->d_name, file_path);   /*Computes rute (overwritten every iteration)*/
            printf("Got %s.\n", file_path);
            pthread_create(&thList[nThreads], NULL, reader_thread, (void * )file_path)  

            nThreads++; 
        }       
    }

    printf("readdir: %s\n", strerror (errno ));     /*Just in case*/

    for (i=0; i<nThreads ; i++)
        pthread_join(thList[i], NULL)

    if (file_path)
        free(file_path);

    return 0;

}
```

My problem here is that, although paths are computed perfectly, the threads don't seem to receive the correct argument. They all read the same file. This is the output I get:

```
Got test/testB.
Got test/testA.
readdir: Success
Opened test/testA.
Thread 139976911939328 -> test/testA: 3536
Thread 139976911939328 -> test/testA: 37
Thread 139976911939328 -> test/testA: -38
Thread 139976911939328 -> test/testA: -985
Opened test/testA.
Thread 139976903546624 -> test/testA: 3536
Thread 139976903546624 -> test/testA: 37
Thread 139976903546624 -> test/testA: -38
Thread 139976903546624 -> test/testA: -985
```

If I join the threads before the next one begins, it works OK. So I assume there is a critical section somewhere, but I don't really know how to find it. I have tried mutexing the whole thread function:

```
void * reader_thread (void * arg)
{   

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_file);
    /*...*/
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_file);

}
```

And also, mutexing the while loop in the second function. Even both at the same time. But it won't work in any way. By the way, mutex_file is a global variable, which is init'd by `pthread_mutex_init()` in `main()`.

I would really appreciate a piece of advice with this, as I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. I would also appreciate some good reference or book, as mutexes and System V semaphores are feeling a bit difficult to me.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you are passing exactly the same pointer as file path to both threads. As a result, they read file name from the same string and end up reading the same file. Actually, you get a little bit lucky here because in reality you have a race condition — you update the contents of the string pointer by `file_path` while firing up threads that read from that pointer, so you may end up with a thread reading that memory while it is being changed. What you have to do is allocate an argument for each thread separately (i.e. call `malloc` and related logic in your `while` loop), and then free those arguments once thread is exited.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, my trouble was the race condition you mentioned, as file_path changes every iteration. I have used the mutex to lock right before `get_file_path()` and unlock right before `fclose(f);` in the thread function. Seems to work. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're using the same file_path buffer for all threads, just loading it over and over again with the next name. You need to allocate a new string for each thread, and have each thread delete the string after using it.

*edit*

Since you already have an array of threads, you could just make a parallel array of char[], each holding the filename for the corresponding thread. This would avoid malloc/free.